# Clearing pending requests after logging out of Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring application made with Spring Boot, which uses Spring Security for authentication.

When I log in, the first page I show has to load a lot of resources, and does so by using AJAX in some cases and using Spring URLs as `src` for images.

If I logout when some of these requests are still pending and then log in again, the login does not take me to my home page, but to the result of one of those pending requests, so instead of getting to the home page I get redirected to one of the images that was being loaded.

So... is there any way to clear the list of pending requests when a user logs out? (or any other solution that might help me fix this issue)

Thanks!

Comment: after logout is complete just redirect to the base url of your application.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but somehow the other requests (at least one of them) stay in the "queue" or whatever and the problem still stands... I'm going to edit the question, though, because I realised that not all other requests are being made using AJAX. Thanks!

Comment: logout operation should be plain post / get request to the server. on the backend you send a redirect code back to the browser